# EMDK for .NET - unable to install EMDK- visual studio not found - WPF

Tags: wpf, zebra-printers, motorola-emdk

I Windows Server 2019 Standard and visual studio professional 2019 and I'm trying to install **emdk-m-020802 V2.8**.

I get this error: EMDK for .NET - unable to install EMDK- visual studio not found.

I have in another server with: Windows Server 2019 Datacenter and visual studio professional 2019. In this server the installation of emdk-m-020802 V2.8 is ok.

Also in my local PC I have Windows 10 pro and visual studio professional 2019. In this server the installation of emdk-m-020802 V2.8 is ok.

**emdk-m-020802 V2.8**.

Things I tried:

- Install newer version emdk-m-020900 V2.9 - I still getting the am error in the installation.
- Restart the server.
- Install as administrator.
- Uninstall and install the Visual 2019 and Restart the server.

In each time the installation don't recognize the Visual studio 2019 installation

[image]

Answer (score 1):

EMDK for .NET is looking for Visual Studio 2008 or 2005 - it is designed for targeting Windows Mobile or Windows CE devices and VS2008 is the most recent of VS that supports those devices.

Comment: Hi Darryn,
 I have in another server with: Windows Server 2019 Datacenter and visual studio professional 2019. In this server the installation of emdk-m-020802 V2.8 is ok.

Also in my local PC I have Windows 10 pro and visual studio professional 2019. In this server the installation of emdk-m-020802 V2.8 is ok.